# Docker - Install CI Server on a remote host

Tags: docker

I have a remote host that is already running a Ubuntu OS. I want to now create a docker file that would help me run a Continuous Integration server like TeamCity on this remote host.

I understand that I create a DockerFile from a base image like Ubuntu. But I do not need another Ubuntu filesystem on a Ubuntu host. How can I handle this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need all the userspace files of Ubuntu, then this is how Docker operates - in order to promise that you can lift your container off an Ubuntu machine and run it on a different Linux, Docker has its own copy of everything above the kernel.  This will be shared amongst every container based on Ubuntu, but still it's a couple of hundred megs of disk space.

If you don't need so much from Ubuntu, then you can start with a much smaller image such as [busybox](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/busybox/).

You could also create a fairly empty container image and map parts of your Ubuntu disk to be visible using [the -v option](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/).  But then you won't have everything you need inside the container.

Comment: Ok I get the point. The link here is just the kernel of the underlying OS. Now let's say I have set up my CI server on the remote Ubuntu host, I have configured my CI server by adding projects that I want to build and run. What happens if I restart my docker container? Would all the projects that I have added as part of my CI server disappear? How do I even make sure that all my projects on my CI server are preserved after a restart of my docker container?

Comment: Put the application (the CI system programs and config) in the container; put the data (the code you are building) in a volume.  https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/

Comment: You may also want to look at http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#commit .  But this is now some distance from your original question.